# Element Push without closing tag JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to execute the below recursive function, the problem is `ul` Since when the function is called I'm pushing a `ul` tag and at the end of `forEach` I'm closing it. Incase if I change `outputArray.push(<ul>)` with the closing `</ul>` then it works fine, but that won't serve my purpose.

Any way around it?

Note : It is a recursive function.

```js
function flatten(data, outputArray) {
      outputArray.push(<ul>)
        data.forEach(function (asset){
            if(asset.children.length) {
              outputArray.push(<li><button onClick={_ => this.appendAssets(asset.name)}>{asset.name}</button></li>);
              flatten(asset.children, outputArray);
            }
            else{
              outputArray.push(<li><button onClick={_ => this.appendAssets(asset.name)}>{asset.name}</button></li>);
            }
        });
      outputArray.push(</ul>)
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of putting them into an array? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just going to render into dom. Just need the ul and li to retain the structure.

Comment: Why don't you just use pure JSX to render the ul and within it map over the array into li elements?

Comment: There would be multiple `ul` depending on the data what I receive. Kinda dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

The best thing you an do is:

```
let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = [];
```

You can loop over and push as much JSX li's into arr1 as you'd like:

```
arr1.push(<li>Some content</li>);
```

You then can push the entire contents of arr1 into arr2, wrapped with ul tags:

```
arr2.push(<ul>{arr1}</ul>);
```

Then simply render and return it:

```
render(){
return (
<div>{arr2}</div>
)
}
```

This works really well when you need to generate a grid with a variable number of Rows and Cols.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following structure

```
let enclosure = [];
loop {
   enclosure.push(jsx);
}
return (<ul>{enclosre}</ul>);
```